# UAA server - org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication, cloudfoundry-uaa

The client needs to get a token from UAA server, but when the request was sent, I alway got the error as follows:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent[source=org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@48d8d90a: Principal: admin-portal-ui; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, clientId=admin-portal-ui; Not granted any authorities]
```

The UAA server log are shown below:

```
[2016-11-21 18:40:57.008] cloudfoundry-identity-server - ???? [http-apr-8080-exec-2] .... DEBUG --- UaaRequestMatcher: [loginAuthorizeRequestMatcherOld] Checking match of request : '/uaa/oauth/token'; '/uaa/oauth/authorize' with parameters={login={} and headers {accept=[application/json]}
[2016-11-21 18:40:57.008] cloudfoundry-identity-server - ???? [http-apr-8080-exec-2] .... DEBUG --- UaaRequestMatcher: [passcodeTokenMatcher] Checking match of request : '/uaa/oauth/token'; '/uaa/oauth/token' with parameters={grant_type=password, passcode=} and headers {accept=[application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded]}
[2016-11-21 18:40:57.008] cloudfoundry-identity-server - ???? [http-apr-8080-exec-2] .... DEBUG --- CorsFilter: CORS Processing request: URI: /uaa/oauth/token; Scheme: http; Host: localhost; Port: 8080; Origin: http://localhost:81; Method: POST
[2016-11-21 18:40:57.008] cloudfoundry-identity-server - ???? [http-apr-8080-exec-2] .... DEBUG --- CorsFilter: Request cross origin request has passed validation.
[2016-11-21 18:40:57.012] cloudfoundry-identity-server - ???? [http-apr-8080-exec-2] .... DEBUG --- DisableIdTokenResponseTypeFilter: Processing id_token disable filter
[2016-11-21 18:40:57.012] cloudfoundry-identity-server - ???? [http-apr-8080-exec-2] .... DEBUG --- DisableIdTokenResponseTypeFilter: pre id_token disable:false pathinfo:null request_uri:/uaa/oauth/token response_type:token
[2016-11-21 18:40:57.012] cloudfoundry-identity-server - ???? [http-apr-8080-exec-2] .... DEBUG --- DisableIdTokenResponseTypeFilter: post id_token disable:false pathinfo:null request_uri:/uaa/oauth/token response_type:token
[2016-11-21 18:40:57.012] cloudfoundry-identity-server - ???? [http-apr-8080-exec-2] .... DEBUG --- SecurityFilterChainPostProcessor$HttpsEnforcementFilter: Filter chain 'tokenEndpointSecurity' processing request POST /uaa/oauth/token
[2016-11-21 18:40:57.095] cloudfoundry-identity-server - ???? [http-apr-8080-exec-2] ....  INFO --- Audit: PrincipalAuthenticationFailure ('null'): principal=admin-portal-ui, origin=[127.0.0.1], identityZoneId=[uaa]
[2016-11-21 18:40:57.095] cloudfoundry-identity-server - ???? [http-apr-8080-exec-2] ....  INFO --- Audit: ClientAuthenticationFailure ('Bad credentials'): principal=admin-portal-ui, origin=[remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, clientId=admin-portal-ui], identityZoneId=[uaa]
[2016-11-21 18:40:57.095] cloudfoundry-identity-server - ???? [http-apr-8080-exec-2] .... DEBUG --- CorsFilter: CORS processing completed for: URI: /uaa/oauth/token; Scheme: http; Host: localhost; Port: 8080; Origin: http://localhost:81; Method: POST Status:401
```

Below is the login-server-security.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">

    <oauth:resource-server id="oauthResourceAuthenticationFilter" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        resource-id="oauth" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

    <http name="secFilterLoginServerAuthenticate" request-matcher-ref="loginAuthenticateRequestMatcher" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          authentication-manager-ref="loginAuthenticationMgr" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" use-expressions="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <custom-filter ref="oauthResourceAuthenticationFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <!-- scope authentication filter configured with a scope authentication manager -->
        <custom-filter ref="oauthLoginScopeAuthenticatingFilter" after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>

    <bean id="loginAuthenticateRequestMatcher" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.security.web.UaaRequestMatcher">
        <constructor-arg value="/authenticate" />
        <property name="accept" value="application/json" />
        <property name="headers">
            <map>
                <entry key="Authorization" value="bearer "  />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <sec:http name="secFilterAuthenticateOpen"  pattern="/authenticate/**" security="none" />

    <http name="secFilterLoginServerAuthorize" request-matcher-ref="loginAuthorizeRequestMatcher" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        authentication-manager-ref="loginAuthenticationMgr" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" use-expressions="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <custom-filter ref="backwardsCompatibleScopeParameter" position="FIRST"/>
        <custom-filter ref="oauthResourceAuthenticationFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <!-- scope authentication filter configured with a scope authentication manager -->
        <custom-filter ref="oauthLoginScopeAuthenticatingFilter" after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <custom-filter ref="loginAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>

    <bean id="loginAuthorizeRequestMatcher" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.security.web.UaaRequestMatcher">
        <constructor-arg value="/oauth/authorize" />
        <property name="accept" value="application/json" />
        <property name="parameters">
            <map>
                <entry key="source" value="login" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <http name="secFilterLoginServerToken" request-matcher-ref="loginTokenRequestMatcher" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          authentication-manager-ref="loginAuthenticationMgr" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" use-expressions="false">
        <!--
          This represents a /oauth/token requests that gets passed through
          from the login server. It assumes that the User has been authenticated
          It requires that:
           - userid parameter exists
           - client_id and client_secret are present
           - Bearer token belongs to login server (oauth.login) validated as resource="oauth"
        -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <!-- the oauthResourceAuthenticationFilter validates the Bearer token
             TODO, if there is no token this filter must throw.
             What we need is scope=oauth.login
         -->
        <custom-filter ref="backwardsCompatibleScopeParameter" position="FIRST"/>
        <custom-filter ref="oauthResourceAuthenticationFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <!-- scope authentication filter configured with a scope authentication manager -->
        <custom-filter ref="oauthLoginScopeAuthenticatingFilter" after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <!-- filter to validate the client_id and client_secret -->
        <custom-filter ref="loginClientParameterAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <!-- The loginServerTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter validates the user or creates one-->
        <custom-filter ref="loginServerTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>

    <bean id="oauthLoginScopeAuthenticatingFilter" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.authentication.manager.ScopeAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="oauthLoginAuthManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthLoginAuthManager" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.authentication.manager.ScopeAuthenticationManager">
        <property name="requiredScopes">
            <list>
                <value type="java.lang.String">oauth.login</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginTokenRequestMatcher" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.security.web.UaaRequestMatcher">
        <constructor-arg value="/oauth/token" />
        <property name="accept" value="application/json" />
        <property name="headers">
            <map>
                <entry key="Authorization" value="bearer " />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="parameters">
            <map>
                <entry key="source" value="login" />
                <entry key="grant_type" value="password" />
                <entry key="add_new" value="" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginServerTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.authentication.LoginServerTokenEndpointFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="loginAuthenticationMgr" />
        <constructor-arg ref="authorizationRequestManager"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="addNewUserParameters"/>
        <property name="authenticationDetailsSource" ref="authenticationDetailsSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginClientParameterAuthenticationFilter" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.authentication.LoginClientParametersAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="clientAuthenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Support for older login servers -->
    <http name="secFilterLoginServerAuthorizeOld" request-matcher-ref="loginAuthorizeRequestMatcherOld" create-session="always" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        authentication-manager-ref="loginAuthenticationMgr" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" use-expressions="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <custom-filter ref="backwardsCompatibleScopeParameter" position="FIRST"/>
        <custom-filter ref="oauthResourceAuthenticationFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <custom-filter ref="loginAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>

    <bean id="loginAuthorizeRequestMatcherOld" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.security.web.UaaRequestMatcher">
        <constructor-arg value="/oauth/authorize" />
        <property name="accept" value="application/json" />
        <property name="parameters">
            <map>
                <entry key="login" value="{" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- End support for older login servers -->
    <util:list id="addNewUserParameters" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <value>login</value>
        <value>username</value>
        <value>user_id</value>
        <value>origin</value>
        <value>given_name</value>
        <value>family_name</value>
        <value>email</value>
        <value>authorities</value>
    </util:list>

    <bean id="loginAuthenticationFilter" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.authentication.AuthzAuthenticationFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="loginAuthenticationMgr" />
        <property name="parameterNames" ref="addNewUserParameters"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginAuthenticationMgr" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.authentication.manager.LoginAuthenticationManager">
        <property name="userDatabase" ref="userDatabase" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.authentication.RemoteAuthenticationEndpoint">
        <constructor-arg ref="zoneAwareAuthzAuthenticationManager" />
        <property name="loginAuthenticationManager" ref="loginAuthenticationMgr"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="codeStore" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.codestore.JdbcExpiringCodeStore">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="passwordResetEndpoints" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.account.PasswordResetEndpoint">
        <constructor-arg ref="resetPasswordService"/>
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.web.ExceptionReportHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="codeStore" ref="codeStore"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="changeEmailEndpoints" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.scim.endpoints.ChangeEmailEndpoints">
        <constructor-arg ref="scimUserProvisioning"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="codeStore"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetailsService"/>
    </bean>

    <http name="secFilterLoginServerPasswordEndpoints" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="emptyAuthenticationManager"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" pattern="/password_*" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  use-expressions="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="scope=oauth.login" />
        <custom-filter ref="oauthResourceAuthenticationFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>

    <http name="secFilterLoginServerEmailEndpoints" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="emptyAuthenticationManager"
          access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" pattern="/email_*" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" use-expressions="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="scope=oauth.login" />
        <custom-filter ref="oauthResourceAuthenticationFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>
</beans>
```

And there is a configuration uaa.yml as follows:

```
login:
  #Disable create account and forgot password links on the Login Server
  selfServiceLinksEnabled: false
  # Configure branding for the UAA
  branding:
    companyName: Consent2Share
    productLogo: 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
#Configure to enable to limit login failure attempts
authentication:
  policy:
    lockoutAfterFailures: 5
    countFailuresWithinSeconds: 3600
    lockoutPeriodSeconds: 600
# Patient User will use the e-mail server configured in this section to send e-mails
# Please configure valid e-mail server below to connect to SMTP server
# Configure host, port, username and password per environment
smtp:
  host: ${UAA_SMTP_HOST}
  port: ${UAA_SMTP_PORT}
  user: ${UAA_SMTP_USER}
  password: ${UAA_SMTP_PASSWORD}
  javaMailProperties:
    mail:
      smtp:
        auth: true
        starttls:
          enable: true
        ssl:
          trust: ${UAA_SMTP_HOST}
      debug: true
spring_profiles: mysql # default is empty
database:
  driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver # only if spring_profiles=mysql
  url: jdbc:mysql://${C2S_DB_HOST:localhost}:${C2S_DB_PORT:3306}/uaa # only if spring_profiles=mysql
  username: root # only if spring_profiles=mysql
  password: ${UAA_DB_PASSWORD:wtzhou} # only if spring_profiles=mysql
oauth:
  clients:
    admin:
      secret: adminsecret
      authorized-grant-types: client_credentials
      scope: uaa.none
      authorities: uaa.admin,clients.read,clients.write,clients.secret,scim.read,scim.write,clients.admin
    cf: # this client is needed for cf cli and uaac cli to act on user's behalf
      authorized-grant-types: implicit,password,refresh_token
      scope: uaa.user,cloud_controller.read,cloud_controller.write,openid,password.write,scim.userids,cloud_controller.admin,scim.read,scim.write
      authorities: uaa.none
      autoapprove: true
    patient-portal-ui:
      authorized-grant-types: password
      #secret: changeit
      secret: loginsecret
      scope: openid,phr.hie_read,phr.hie_write,phr.patient_read,pcm.provider_read,pcm.provider_create,pcm.provider_delete,pcm.consent_read,pcm.consent_create,pcm.consent_update,pcm.consent_delete,pcm.consent_sign,pcm.consent_revoke,pcm.clinicalDocument_read,pcm.clinicalDocument_create,pcm.clinicalDocument_delete,pcm.activity_read,ppUI.access,tryPolicy.clinicalDocument_read
      authorities: uaa.resource
    admin-portal-ui:
      authorized-grant-types: password
      secret: loginsecret
      scope: openid,scim.write,scim.read,scim.create,phr.allPatientProfiles_read,phr.hie_write,phr.allPatients_read,phr.patient_read,registration.write,uaa.admin,patientUser.read,patientUser.write,adminUI.access,pep.patient_read
      authorities: uaa.resource
    patient-user:
      secret: loginsecret
      authorized-grant-types: client_credentials
      scope: uaa.none
      authorities: phr.patient_read,phr.allPatientProfiles_read,scim.write,scim.read,scim.create,uaa.admin
    azhec-hie:
      secret: loginsecret
      authorized-grant-types: client_credentials
      scope: uaa.none
      authorities: pep.patient_read
    sysadmin:
      secret: loginsecret
      authorized-grant-types: client_credentials
      scope: uaa.none
      authorities: patientUser.scope_assign,scim.write,scim.read,scim.create,uaa.admin
scim:
  groups:
    phr.hie_read: Access your health information
    phr.hie_write: Add your health information
    phr.patient_read: Access the patient details
    pcm.provider_read: Access provider from list
    pcm.provider_create: Create new provider
    pcm.provider_delete: Delete provider from list
    pcm.consent_read: Access and display your consent
    pcm.consent_create: Add new consent
    pcm.consent_update: Update current consent
    pcm.consent_delete: Delete a consent
    pcm.consent_sign: Sign consent
    pcm.consent_revoke: Revoke current consent
    pcm.clinicalDocument_read: Access and display clinical document
    pcm.clinicalDocument_create: Create new clinical document
    pcm.clinicalDocument_delete: Delete current clinical document
    pcm.activity_read: Access the patient activity history
    ppUI.access: Access patient portal UI
    pep.patient_read: Access policy enforcement point
    tryPolicy.clinicalDocument_read: View policies applied on clinical document
    patientUser.scope_assign: Allows Sysadmin to assign scopes to users
  users:
#  Configure additional c2s staff admin(users) as:
#    - EmailId | password | EmailId | FirstName | LastName | <Comma saperated list of permissions>
#  For example:  - consent2share@gmail.com|admin|consent2share@gmail.com|admin|admin|openid,scim.write,scim.read,scim.create,phr.allPatientProfiles_read,phr.hie_write,phr.allPatients_read,phr.patient_read,registration.write,uaa.admin,patientUser.read,patientUser.write,adminUI.access
    - consent2share@gmail.com|admin|consent2share@gmail.com|admin|admin|openid,scim.write,scim.read,scim.create,phr.allPatientProfiles_read,phr.hie_write,phr.allPatients_read,phr.patient_read,registration.write,uaa.admin,patientUser.read,patientUser.write,adminUI.access
# C2S_APP_HOST and C2S_APP_PORT are related to edge server api
c2s:
  uaa:
    host: http://${C2S_APP_HOST:localhost}:${C2S_APP_PORT:81}/uaa
jwt:
  token:
    verification-key: |
      -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
      MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA0m59l2u9iDnMbrXHfqkO
      rn2dVQ3vfBJqcDuFUK03d+1PZGbVlNCqnkpIJ8syFppW8ljnWweP7+LiWpRoz0I7
      fYb3d8TjhV86Y997Fl4DBrxgM6KTJOuE/uxnoDhZQ14LgOU2ckXjOzOdTsnGMKQB
      LCl0vpcXBtFLMaSbpv1ozi8h7DJyVZ6EnFQZUWGdgTMhDrmqevfx95U/16c5WBDO
      kqwIn7Glry9n9Suxygbf8g5AzpWcusZgDLIIZ7JTUldBb8qU2a0Dl4mvLZOn4wPo
      jfj9Cw2QICsc5+Pwf21fP+hzf+1WSRHbnYv8uanRO0gZ8ekGaghM/2H6gqJbo2nI
      JwIDAQAB
      -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    signing-key: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      MIIEowIBAAKCAQEA0m59l2u9iDnMbrXHfqkOrn2dVQ3vfBJqcDuFUK03d+1PZGbV
      lNCqnkpIJ8syFppW8ljnWweP7+LiWpRoz0I7fYb3d8TjhV86Y997Fl4DBrxgM6KT
      JOuE/uxnoDhZQ14LgOU2ckXjOzOdTsnGMKQBLCl0vpcXBtFLMaSbpv1ozi8h7DJy
      VZ6EnFQZUWGdgTMhDrmqevfx95U/16c5WBDOkqwIn7Glry9n9Suxygbf8g5AzpWc
      usZgDLIIZ7JTUldBb8qU2a0Dl4mvLZOn4wPojfj9Cw2QICsc5+Pwf21fP+hzf+1W
      SRHbnYv8uanRO0gZ8ekGaghM/2H6gqJbo2nIJwIDAQABAoIBAHPV9rSfzllq16op
      zoNetIJBC5aCcU4vJQBbA2wBrgMKUyXFpdSheQphgY7GP/BJTYtifRiS9RzsHAYY
      pAlTQEQ9Q4RekZAdd5r6rlsFrUzL7Xj/CVjNfQyHPhPocNqwrkxp4KrO5eL06qcw
      UzT7UtnoiCdSLI7IL0hIgJZP8J1uPNdXH+kkDEHE9xzU1q0vsi8nBLlim+ioYfEa
      Q/Q/ovMNviLKVs+ZUz+wayglDbCzsevuU+dh3Gmfc98DJw6n6iClpd4fDPqvhxUO
      BDeQT1mFeHxexDse/kH9nygxT6E4wlU1sw0TQANcT6sHReyHT1TlwnWlCQzoR3l2
      RmkzUsECgYEA8W/VIkfyYdUd5ri+yJ3iLdYF2tDvkiuzVmJeA5AK2KO1fNc7cSPK
      /sShHruc0WWZKWiR8Tp3d1XwA2rHMFHwC78RsTds+NpROs3Ya5sWd5mvmpEBbL+z
      cl3AU9NLHVvsZjogmgI9HIMTTl4ld7GDsFMt0qlCDztqG6W/iguQCx8CgYEA3x/j
      UkP45/PaFWd5c1DkWvmfmi9UxrIM7KeyBtDExGIkffwBMWFMCWm9DODw14bpnqAA
      jH5AhQCzVYaXIdp12b+1+eOOckYHwzjWOFpJ3nLgNK3wi067jVp0N0UfgV5nfYw/
      +YoHfYRCGsM91fowh7wLcyPPwmSAbQAKwbOZKfkCgYEAnccDdZ+m2iA3pitdIiVr
      RaDzuoeHx/IfBHjMD2/2ZpS1aZwOEGXfppZA5KCeXokSimj31rjqkWXrr4/8E6u4
      PzTiDvm1kPq60r7qi4eSKx6YD15rm/G7ByYVJbKTB+CmoDekToDgBt3xo+kKeyna
      cUQqUdyieunM8bxja4ca3ukCgYAfrDAhomJ30qa3eRvFYcs4msysH2HiXq30/g0I
      aKQ12FSjyZ0FvHEFuQvMAzZM8erByKarStSvzJyoXFWhyZgHE+6qDUJQOF6ruKq4
      DyEDQb1P3Q0TSVbYRunOWrKRM6xvJvSB4LUVfSvBDsv9TumKqwfZDVFVn9yXHHVq
      b6sjSQKBgDkcyYkAjpOHoG3XKMw06OE4OKpP9N6qU8uZOuA8ZF9ZyR7vFf4bCsKv
      QH+xY/4h8tgL+eASz5QWhj8DItm8wYGI5lKJr8f36jk0JLPUXODyDAeN6ekXY9LI
      fudkijw0dnh28LJqbkFF5wLNtATzyCfzjp+czrPMn9uqLNKt/iVD
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I have been tried to find the reason for a long time, but I still cannot get it done. Could anyone help me to figure out what is the root cause for the error? Any reply will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some authorities to the client (admin-portal-ui) you are using. Most likely adding `oauth.login` should do.

Please refer to sample client xml [oauth-clients.xml](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/uaa/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/oauth-clients.xml) on github uaa repo.
You may need something similar to the `login` client. In this xml, you can find many more authorities added to the login client. You can try adding all of them.

Another point you may want to check is the origin of the user, if you are trying to acquire token on behalf of the user without his password. In this case the origin must NOT be `uaa`